# Как будто их(,) долгие века(,) лизали морские волны.

Tags: орфография

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли выделение уточнения в данном случае? И уточнение ли это -"долгие века"? Ведь если не поставить хотя бы первую запятую, то фразу можно прочитать так, будто "морские волны лизали непосредственно сами "долгие века".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Как будто** их долгие века **лизали** морские волны.

Этот оборот **со значением уподобления** не обособляется, для проверки союз КАК БУДТО  можно изъять из предложения.

**Примеры:** Словно белою косынкой подвязалася сосна. Как соломинкой пьёшь мою душу.

Но вообще говоря, **предложение напоминает придаточное сравнительное** с союзом КАК БУДТО, например: Камни стали круглыми, как будто их долгие века лизали морские волны.

Comment: На самом деле, это придаточное предложение. И выглядит оно во фразе немного по другому. Абзац: "Теперь, установленный так, как ему подобало стоять, Камень напоминал очертаниями неправильной формы пирамиду. Чуть выше обычного человеческого роста, с обкатанными, сглаженными рёбрами. Будто их долгие века лизали морские волны."

Comment: Это прием парцелляции,  придаточное сравнительное выделено в самостоятельное предложение.

Comment: Не знал, что пользуюсь какими-либо приёмами. Смайл. Придётся принять как факт, что читатель сам должен понять, о чём именно идёт речь. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В случае обособления "долгие века" станет уточнением местоимения "их" и получится, что долгие века подверглись облизыванию со стороны морских волн. Выделять "долгие века" не нужно - это обстоятельсво времени.

Answer (score 0):

Как будто их долгие века ласкали морские волны. В данном предложении 
"долгие века " не является оборотом и, следовательно, не обособляется. Уточнение должно всегда стоять после уточняемого члена и отвечать на тот же самый вопрос + слово "именно". Например, как будто их (сколько?) четыреста лет (сколько именно?), долгие века, ласкали морские волны. Вот в этом случае "долгие века" будет уточнением.